# word relatedness, defining character of a word

Tags: computational-linguistics, corpora

How can NLP tell the word "stool" is closely related to the word "dirty?" When the word relationship is based on a corpus, most likely the word "stool" is related to some medical terms such as "bloody" "pale" "solid," etc. But the defining character should be "dirty" in people's mind. I wonder how NLP handles that? i.e., given the word "stool," return a high score of relatedness to the word "dirty."

Thank you.

Comment: For relatedness, see third point [here](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/19052/13238). For "character" or associations, much harder, because these are vague, often individual and, most importantly, mental conceptions that are not directly encoded in the language (of course any meaning is somewhat purely conceptual, but lexical relatedness manifests stronglier in language than associations and emotions), you'd need a lot of world knowledge in order to automatically detect such connotations which is much harder to do than checking for semantic similarity (like co-hyponyms).

Comment: That's you again, Lemontree, thank you very much for replying! It's intuitive to me that hoping the NLP to figure out emotions is a stretch. That was not my intent of the question. My original question is more like whether there is an NLP technique to recognize a piece of common sense, e.g., "stool" is "dirty" This relationship is not vague, not unique to individual.

Comment: So the only reason for this to be difficult, let me paraphrase your words a little bit, is that a common sense like this will just be in the back of people's mind, and it will unlikely to be explicitly said "stool is dirty" many times in daily communication, and therefore the evidence of this fact will not exist in any corpus (meaning "not directly encoded in the language"). Is that a correct understanding of your reply? Thank you.

Comment: Do you know what "stool" means?

Comment: stool in the sense of "feces"

Comment: @bizbuzz Yes, this is what I meant. It's that "background knowledge" or "common sense" or "world knowledge" that is problematic, because humans have that knowledge while computers don't. And just as you say, expressions of such side-meanings in language like "stool is dirty" or "Mercedes is an expensive car" are rather unlikely to occur in explicit expressions and are thus harder for a computer to determine than e.g. checking which words often occur in the same positions (like the milk/water example in the post I linked to) or which sets of words often occur in the same sentence...

Comment: ... (like the examples with "stool", "blood" and "solid" you mentioned, which would be rather easy to exract from a corpus because this is a kind of relationship that is actually reflected in language, while the "defining character", as you call it, in the sense of something like connotation or common sense, not that much).

Answer (score 1):

The closest answer to your question I can think of would be [Word2Vec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word2vec). The language models produced by it tend to capture semantic relationships between words very well. They can answer questions such as "*woman* is to *queen* as *man* is to *X*" or calculate the "semantic distance" (whatever that means exactly) between two words. Among others, there are implementations in C and Python. The latter is introduced [here](http://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html).